How do I resolve net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES on chromium browsers
I am fetching data from the Pokemon API and it seems to be able to fetch without error when I use the search function or just regular loading of the pokemon but when I filter the pokemon by type, the console shows many errors like
   GET https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/terapagos-stellar net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

This error occurs on both Brave Browser and Chromium but I do not experience this on Firefox.
Here is my code for the fetching of data:
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchPokemon() {
            setIsLoading(true);
            let url = URL;
            if (filter) {
                url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=1302&offset=0";
            }
            const res = await fetch(url);
            const data = await res.json();
            const result = data.results;
            setNext(data.next);
            setPrev(data.previous);
            const pokemonInfo = await Promise.all(
                result.map(async (pokemon) => {
                    const res = await fetch(
                        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`
                    );
                    return res.json();
                })
            );
            setIsLoading(false);
            if (!search && !filter) {
                setData(pokemonInfo);
            }
        }
        fetchPokemon();

        async function fetchPokemonByType(type) {
            setData([]);
            const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${type}`);
            const data = await res.json();
            const pokemonList =
                data.pokemon?.map((pokemon) => pokemon.pokemon.name) || [];
            const pokemonInfo = await Promise.all(
                pokemonList.map(async (name) => {
                    const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`);
                    return res.json();
                })
            );

            !search && setData(pokemonInfo);
        }
        fetchPokemonByType(filter);

        async function searchPokemon() {
            if (search !== "") {
                const res = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${search}`);
                if (res.ok) {
                    const data = await res.json();
                    setData([data]);
                    setSearchError("");
                } else {
                    setSearchError("There is no such Pokémon");
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            }
        }
        searchPokemon();
    }, [URL, filter, search]);
    useEffect(() => {}, [search]);


The only thing that worked so far was disabling cache in dev tools.
Also tried incognito but didn't work either
edit: tried with disable cache again and not working either
edit 2: seems like its working properly on my windows PC but just doesn't work on my linux ubuntu laptop

You’re trying to make 1k+ requests in parallel? That’s probably the problem, but you shouldn’t even make 1k+ requests in a row with lesser concurrency – that’s a ton of burst traffic for a single client, and the provider will probably block you if you get enough traffic. Use batch APIs, lazy load, etc.
